# HQL NHibernate - "where clause" of a collection of an entity

Tags: nhibernate, join, hql

I'm using NHibernate 3.2

Here is what i want to do (all atempts failed):

```
from Car c where (c.Tires.elements.Brand = 'Goodyear')
```

OR

```
from Car c, elements(c.Tires) as t where t.Brand = 'Goodyear'
```

Is it possible to do it without using joins? And how to do it with joins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from Car c
inner join c.Tires t
where t.Brand = 'Goodyear'
```

Comment: It's returning both a Car and a Tire, should this happen?